# Istio pilot discovery http api documents?

Tags: istio

pilot discovery has exposed http service, but there is no documents on it. How can I do query like listing all registered services through pilot api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the related document and code:

Debug Interface:

https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/pilot/pkg/proxy/envoy/v2

```
PILOT=istio-pilot.istio-system:9093

# What is sent to envoy
# Listeners and routes
curl $PILOT/debug/adsz

# Endpoints
curl $PILOT/debug/edsz

# Clusters
curl $PILOT/debug/cdsz

# General metrics
curl $PILOT/metrics

# All services/external services from all registries
curl $PILOT/debug/registryz

# All endpoints
curl $PILOT/debug/endpointz[?brief=1]

# All configs.
curl $PILOT/debug/configz
```

List all endpoints:
/v1/registration

https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pilot/pkg/proxy/envoy/discovery.go#L141

```
pprof
/debug/pprof/

healthz
/ready


mux.HandleFunc("/debug/edsz", s.edsz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/adsz", s.adsz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/cdsz", cdsz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/syncz", Syncz)

mux.HandleFunc("/debug/registryz", s.registryz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/endpointz", s.endpointz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/endpointShardz", s.endpointShardz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/workloadz", s.workloadz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/configz", s.configz)

mux.HandleFunc("/debug/authenticationz", s.authenticationz)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/config_dump", s.ConfigDump)
mux.HandleFunc("/debug/push_status", s.PushStatusHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

i used it like this and it worked . tested on istio 1.7

connect to istiod:

```
kubectl exec -ti < istiod-pod-name > -c discovery -n istio-system -- /bin/bash
```

run pilot-discovery command:

```
pilot-discovery request get metrics | grep citadel
```